# How to Give a posterize effect on imageview?

Tags: android, android-layout, image-processing

i am trying to give a Photoshop posterization effect to imageview.here is a normal image.

[image]

after applying posterization effect it should look like this,this effect is taken from [pixlr image editor](http://pixlr.com/editor/)

[image]

I want exact effect programmatically.

what I have tried is, I am trying to get similar effect with SaturationFilter kind of effect, as I am not able to find posterization method for android.

here is my function http://pastie.org/8007887

and resulting image is,as below which is not looking similar to Photoshop posterized effect, I have tried passing several saturation level,but no luck.i hope some one will guide me in a proper way.

[image]

found some way, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html here is a guidline for posterization effect,and that is applicable for android API level 14,what about device which use API level <14?

Comment: Hi, @AamirKhan did u find the answer ?

Comment: No any answer helped you? Please mark any one if you found helpful else if you found good resource, please post your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a good library available named **[JHLabs' Java Image Processing](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html).**

It has lots of image processing filters available. I also use that library in my application. It is very compatible with Android also.

You can also download **[source code](http://android-jhlabs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk)** and run sample application.

JAR Download : **http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/Filters.zip**

Comment: hello chintan, actually i am not able to download the source code, n i need this immidiately. Can you pls mail me the source code for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi.. You can download using http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/download.html. Please check. If you can't download, let me know. :)

Comment: This is the library which you might have used in your source code, i need source code on this link http://android-jhlabs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/  . here it's showing svn connection error

Comment: I am sorry dear.. I am at work. So I can't send you any type of file from here. :( . But there is one possibility. You can use any type of "grabber" to download all files from a URL like internet download manager or any free tools which download all files from a URL u provided. Its recursive pattern.. http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Other-Internet-Related/Web-Site-Grabber-7.shtml :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following
 1. Android + Open CV
 2. Android + Openframeworks

http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/android-eclipse/
check out sample at
 https://github.com/nkint/ofxPosterize

Answer (score 0):

You can apply such effect by playing on different source code available

I would suggest you to go with this url and check the different effect https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/

The most relevant function i could see is mentioned below, try to modify it according to your need

```
int width = mImage.getWidth();
        int height = mImage.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        mImage.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        for(int x = 0; x < pixels.length; ++x) {
            pixels[x] = (pixels[x] == fromColor) ? targetColor : pixels[x];
        }

        Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, mImage.getConfig());
        newImage.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        return newImage;
```

Comment: Thanks, Will check it