# Apply posterize filter on image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can apply posterize filter on an image in flutter application?
Here is the similar question for android.
[How to Give a posterize effect on imageview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931897/how-to-give-a-posterize-effect-on-imageview)